# how to handle the output from javascript executor(selenium) in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

I have below line of code to find all the matching elements for the given string

```
 var coll = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(string.Format(" var x = $(arguments[0]).find(\":contains('{0}')\"); return x;", strVerify), element);
```

when it finds the match it returns ReadOnlyCollection of IWebElement otherwise it returns ReadOnlyCollection of object.

I am trying to write a common method to handle the output of the above but i couldn't.

meth1 gives below error when it return ReadOnlyCollection of IWebElement

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement]' to type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection

```
public static ReadOnlyCollection<object> meth1(this IWebElement element, IWebDriver driver, string strVerify)
    {
        return (ReadOnlyCollection<object>)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(string.Format( " var x = $(arguments[0]).find(\":contains('{0}')\"); return x;", strVerify), element);
    }
```

methd2 gives below error when it return ReadOnlyCollection of object

"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[System.Object]' to type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement]'."}

```
public static ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> methd2(this IWebElement element, IWebDriver driver, string strVerify)
    {
        return (ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(string.Format(" var x = $(arguments[0]).find(\":contains('{0}')\"); return x;", strVerify), element);
    }
```

How can i write one method to handle both of these outputs.

I really appreciate any help on this. Thanks in advance